# Responsive menu fix

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

Please view it on full screen. Whenever I click on menu arrow to minimize it, I want the text from menu and logo text to dissapear. I just want to leave the icons and make them centered. What would be best approach to do this? I have tried using style display none for one menu and adding another one but there is no transition when adding display property.

```js
function smallNav() {
      let menu = document.getElementById('sidebar-container');
      menu.style.width = "5rem";
}
```

```css
.router-link-active {
    background-color: #2b445f;
    font-weight: 700;
    border-left: 3px solid #1089ff;
}

#right, .left {
    cursor: pointer;
}

#sidebar-container {
    min-height: 100vh;
    transition: 400ms;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 18rem;
    background: #23374d;
}

#sidebar-small {
    min-height: 100vh;
    transition: 400ms;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 0px;
    background: #23374d;
}

#sidebar-container .logo {
    padding: 20px;
}

.menuicon {
    font-size: 24px;
}

.menu {
    transition: 200ms;
}

.menu a {
    color: white;
}

.btn-search {
    right: 5px;
}

.left {
    color: white;
    font-size: 24px;
}

.avatar {
    max-width: 43px;
}

.menu a {
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}

.menu a:hover {
    background-color: #2b445f;
}

ion-icon {
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #fff !important;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    #sidebar-container {
        display: none;
    }

    #mobile {
        display: flex !important;
        flex-direction: column;
        text-align: left;
    }

    #mobile li {
        padding: 20px;
    }

    .btn-search {
        bottom: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css">

<div>
  <div class="d-flex">
    <div class="bg-primary text-left" id="sidebar-container">
      <div class="logo p-3 d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
        <h4 class="text-white">Company Name</h4>
        <div class="i fas fa-chevron-circle-left left" id="left" onClick="smallNav()"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="menu d-flex flex-column">
        <router-link class="nav-link mt-4 d-flex py-3" :to="{name: 'Home'}" exact="true">
          <div class="d-flex align-items-center"> <i class="fas fa-home mr-3 menuicon"> </i>Home</div>
        </router-link>
        <router-link class="nav-link text-white py-3" :to="{name: 'About'}">
          <div class="d-flex align-items-center"> <i class="fas fa-home mr-3 menuicon"></i>Plan </div>
        </router-link>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="w-100">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <div class="container-fluid pl-0 pr-0">
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
          <form class="form-inline my-2 position-relative d-inline-block">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" />
            <button class="btn position-absolute btn-search" type="submit"><i class="fas fa-search"> </i></button>
          </form>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
              <li class="nav-item dropdown"><a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle d-flex align-items-center" id="navbarDropdown" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><img class="avatar mr-2 img-fluid" src="https://www.kindpng.com/picc/m/464-4644512_circle-avatar-picture-png-transparent-png.png" />Jan Kowalski</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Mój profil</a><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Subskrypcja</a>
                  <div class="dropdown-divider"></div><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Wyloguj</a>
                </div>
              </li>
              <div class="d-none" id="mobile">
                <li class="nav-item"></li>Home
                <li class="nav-item"></li>About
                <li class="nav-item"></li>About
              </div>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your source like below.
Your CSS doesn't change, but I added some change in your HTML tags and js code.

```js
function smallNav() {
        let menu = document.getElementById('sidebar-container');
        menu.style.width = "4rem";

        document.getElementById('logo-name').hidden = true;

        for(i=0; document.getElementsByClassName('menu-title').length - 1; i++)
            document.getElementsByClassName('menu-title').item(i).hidden = true;
    }
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="d-flex">
        <div class="bg-primary text-left" id="sidebar-container">
            <div class="logo p-3 d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <h4 class="text-white" id="logo-name">Company Name</h4>
                <div class="i fas fa-chevron-circle-left left" id="left" onClick="smallNav()"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="menu d-flex flex-column">
                <router-link class="nav-link mt-4 d-flex py-3" :to="{name: 'Home'}" exact="true">
                    <div class="d-flex align-items-center"> <i class="fas fa-home mr-3 menuicon"> </i><span class="menu-title">Home</span></div>
                </router-link>
                <router-link class="nav-link text-white py-3" :to="{name: 'About'}">
                    <div class="d-flex align-items-center"> <i class="fas fa-home mr-3 menuicon"></i><span class="menu-title">Plan</span> </div>
                </router-link>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="w-100">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                <div class="container-fluid pl-0 pr-0">
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
                    <form class="form-inline my-2 position-relative d-inline-block">
                        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" />
                        <button class="btn position-absolute btn-search" type="submit"><i class="fas fa-search"> </i></button>
                    </form>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown"><a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle d-flex align-items-center" id="navbarDropdown" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><img class="avatar mr-2 img-fluid" src="https://www.kindpng.com/picc/m/464-4644512_circle-avatar-picture-png-transparent-png.png" />Jan Kowalski</a>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Mój profil</a><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Subskrypcja</a>
                                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Wyloguj</a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <div class="d-none" id="mobile">
                                <li class="nav-item"></li>Home
                                <li class="nav-item"></li>About
                                <li class="nav-item"></li>About
                            </div>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Im getting error on my page
`66:13  error    'i' is not defined                                                                                                                 no-undef`

Comment: Try to change js loop to "for(var i=0; document.getElementsByClassName('menu-title').length - 1; i++)"